# Pycharm how to stop line wrap/break a long import line

Tags: pycharm, python-import, line-breaks

When auto-import a method/module in PyCharm, our import line get wrapped into 2 lines if it is too long.

How can we stop that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is resolved by setting `right margin` with `hard wrap at` set to a very big number eg 666 [view ref](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360004172899/comments/360000560640)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use this in a comment: `@formatter:off` an ...*on*, and it will stop formatting the line and breaking it up into multiple lines. This way, you can still use the formatter in the rest of the document.

In Python

```py
x = ""

# @formatter:off
x = "Is " + "a " + "super " + "long " + "line, " + "that " + "exceeds " + "eighty " + "columns " + "easily"
#@formatter:on

x = ""
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a specific setting related to this:

[image]
[image]

Comment: what is the exact setting is it?

Comment: The one highlighted, I believe.